# address of a character pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, char

When I write the code

```
int main(){
    char c = 'a';
    char *p = &c;
    cout<<*p<<" "<<&c<<" "<<p<<" ";

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

> a aa aa

Why this behaviour only in case of char when other datatype returns the address? And y an extra a appended with the char content?

Comment: You are seeing [undefined behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)

Comment: Along with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727022/access-array-beyond-the-limit-in-c-and-c explains what you are seeing

Comment: If you want to print the addresses, use `cout<<*p<<" "<<(void*)&c<<" "<<(void*)p<<" ";`