# Segmentation fault on nullptr check when incrementing the ptr to iterate over an array

Tags: c++, macos, segmentation-fault, nullptr

The following code, when compiled and run gives a segmentation fault. I was trying out the sample on page 12 of a Tour of C++ on a MacBook.

compilation command -
`clang++ -Wall -std=c++11 -o replacement.o replacement.cpp && ./replacement.o`

Error message - 'zsh: segmentation fault  ./replacement.o'

Full code -

```
#include <iostream>

int count_occurances(char* p, char x)
{
    int count = 0;
    // count number of times x occurs in p
    while (p != nullptr)
    {
        if (*p == x)
            ++count;
        ++p;
    }
    return count;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    char num_array[4] = {'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'};
    std::cout << "Running count occurances array" << count_occurances(num_array, 'b') << "done\n" ;
    return 0;
}
```

Essentially tried to iterate over the array by incrementing the pointer but somehow messing up the nullptr check, as a result it's accessing memory it shouldn't.

Comment: How is `p` ever going to become `nullptr` if all you ever do is increment it? An example like this would normally use a 0 terminated string and check `*p != 0` or pass an array size so you can't go off the end.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access array beyond the limit in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727022/access-array-beyond-the-limit-in-c-and-c)

Comment: BTW: When will the time end people write their own pointer gymnastics? Decades of iterators, now also ranges, standard algorithms... and still `ptr++`? Sure, it is always good to know what is going on on machine level... but it is still enough to sometimes look in the generated assembly... Maybe a good time to watch a talk? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk

Comment: Thank you for your comments - I was just trying to learn the internals of C++, hence tried out this code. I understand that this is not the way to go when writing actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `p != nullptr` is always true as `p = &num_array` which is a valid address.
The `nullptr` comparison should be at the beginning of the function as a general sanity check.

Continuing `++p` beyond the `sizeof(num_array) = 4`, it's an undefined behaviour. In your system it crashes with a segmentation fault.

Either you pass the `sizeof(num_array)` as a function parameter OR assign `0` (NUL) character at the end:

```
char num_array[] = {'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 0};
```

Then the loop should be `while(*p != 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted to check for NULL terminator at the end of the C string
But char array declared and initialized in this way is not NULL terminated

```
char num_array[4] = {'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'};
```

If you want to declare a NULL terminated C style string you can use this way with string literal:

```
char num_array[5] = {"abbc"};
```

And as stated in answer above, pointer p is just an address of the array (or the address of an element of array)
If you want to get or set  the value pointer points to, you have to dereference it:

`*p` or `*(p + index)`

But accessing elements out of array boundary leads to UB and can crash your program.